# How to cache user controls that are inside code blocks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, outputcache

I have an aspx webpage with embedded code block that displays one of the two instances of the same user control. Simplified code:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <%if (true)
                { %>
            <UC:UserControl runat="server" ID="ucFirst"></UC:UserControl>
            <%}
                else
                { %>
            <UC:UserControl runat="server" ID="ucSecond"></UC:UserControl>
            <%} %>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Registered user control is cached:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

However, only `ucFirst` gets cached, while `ucSecond` goes through `Page_Load` and `Page_PreRender` each time I refresh the page, even though it doesn't appear in rendered HTML code at all. Is it possible to either prevent `ucSecond` entirely from loading, or load it just once like `ucFirst` and keep it cached?